# Creating Hourly average based on 2 minutes before and after of time instantaneous in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, average, temporal-database

I have a temporal database with 2 minutes sampling frequency and I want to extract instantaneous hourly values as 00:00, 01:00, 02, ... 23 for each day.
So, I would like to get the average value from average of values :

HH-1:58, HH:00 and HH:02 = Average of HH o'clock

OR

HH-1:59, HH:01 and HH:03  = Average of HH o'clock

Sample Data1:

```
9/28/2007 23:51 -1.68
9/28/2007 23:53 -1.76
9/28/2007 23:55 -1.96
9/28/2007 23:57 -2.02
9/28/2007 23:59 -1.92
9/29/2007 0:01  -1.64
9/29/2007 0:03  -1.76
9/29/2007 0:05  -1.83
9/29/2007 0:07  -1.86
9/29/2007 0:09  -1.94
```

Expected Result:

For 00 midnight:

(-1.92+-1.64+-1.76)/3

Sample Data2:

```
9/28/2007 23:54 -1.44
9/28/2007 23:56 -1.58
9/28/2007 23:58 -2.01
9/29/2007 0:00  -1.52
9/29/2007 0:02  -1.48
9/29/2007 0:04  -1.46
```

Expected Results:

(-2.01+-1.52+-1.48)/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) make anything involving adjacent rows a lot simpler than it used to be. Untried but should be roughly right:

```
select
  date_trunc('hour', newest_time) as average_time,
  (oldest_temp + middle_temp + newest_temp) / 3 as average_temp
from (
  select
    date_trunc('hour', sample_time) as average_time,
    lag(sample_time, 2) over w as oldest_time,
    lag(sample_time, 1) over w as middle_time,
    sample_time as newest_time,
    lag(sample_temp, 2) over w as oldest_temp,
    lag(sample_temp, 1) over w as middle_temp,
    sample_temp as newest_temp
  from
    samples
  window
    w as (order by sample_time)
) as s
where
  oldest_time = newest_time - '4 minutes'::interval and
  middle_time = newest_time - '2 minutes'::interval and
  extract(minute from newest_time) in (2, 3);
```

I've restricted this in the `where` clause to exactly the scenario you've described - latest value at :02 or :03, prior 2 values 2 and 4 minutes before. Just in case you have some missing data which would otherwise give odd results like averaging over a much longer interval.

Comment: I came up with this error.  
ERROR: syntax error at or near "over"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 110

Comment: Try this version, which runs for me (though I haven't put in any data to try it). It seems like I misunderstood `over` a bit; it applies a scope to a single `select` clause, not every window function in the query. I'm not sure if it's possible to apply it to `where` so I used a subquery to accomplish that instead.

Comment: Ahh, it's not possible to use window functions from WHERE, because the WHERE filtering happens first: "The rows considered by a window function are those of the "virtual table" produced by the query's FROM clause as filtered by its WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses if any". So the subquery is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  hr, ts, aval
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hr ORDER BY ts) rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *,
                        DATE_TRUNC('hour', ts) AS hr,
                        AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS aval
                FROM    mytable
                ) q
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```